How to get and keep all perl modules dependencies of a Perl Module
Here is my problem :
I would like to get automatically the dependencies of the XML::Parser module https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-Parser because I need the source for an offline built on multiple different OS and System architectures
I tried with cpan2dist but did not find which option tu use and I also tried to download modules one by one but there just too many dependencies
EDIT :
With your help and advices (many thanks :)) I decided  to use Alien::Expat in order to have a full self sufficient package.
I used libexpat 2.2.10 for compliancy with AIX and now my package is built but I have the following error when trying to parse an XML
https://github.com/grantm/XML-SAX-Base/blob/master/BuildSAXBase.pl#L222
Could you please help me make my package use the Expat libraries built with Alien::Expat?
NB : I'm using AIX 7

Do you mean only perl module dependencies, or also library dependencies like libexpat.so ?

Did you try  https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps ?

scandeps.pl -e 'use XML::Parser'

@clamp, That probably won't work, since XML::Parser has no [Perl] dependencies. It only has build and testing dependencies (though LWP isn't marked as a testing dependency but an actual one) and a binary library dependency.

ty but @ikegami was right, it did not work
(.venv-ansible) ➜  ~ scandeps.pl -e 'use XML::Parser'
No modules found!

Not quite what you asked, but -- you can use CPAN-Mini to make a copy of all of CPAN, which is a superset of what you want. Optionally this copy can include only the latest versions. Stick the copy on a USB drive (or whatever). As @HåkonHægland pointed out, this does not solve the problem of external dependencies.

My goal would have been to have a full perl self sufficient XML::Parser package but I think this cannot be done because of expat.so dependency. Do you confirm?

"to have a self sufficient XML::Parser package": If you include Alien::Expat it could ensure that the library is installed?

I have no network conectivity on this computer. Is it possible to  give the local expat tar.gz as an argument?

I managed to build expat with Alien::Expat but, my XML-SAX-Expat still does not find the expat libraries included in the package.
It throws the following error https://github.com/grantm/XML-SAX-Base/blob/master/BuildSAXBase.pl#L222
How would you make it work?
Help would be  very appreciated

@ArnaudDubois Can you update your question with a detailed description of what you have done so far? Then we can try reproduce

"NB : I'm using AIX 7" Is this problem specific to AIX? Have you tried in e.g. an Ubuntu docker container?

The issue with  AIX is that expat is not installed by default on the operating systems.
That's why I need this

@ArnaudDubois Yes but the errors you get is not specfic to AIX?

Yes they are but not on every systems on which I use the perl package. Only on those wihich do not have expat already installed. On AIX which have expat installed I do not have the error message

Which version of Perl are you using?

5.32.1 and I use the following project : https://github.com/OCSInventory-NG/Packager-for-Unix
I'm trying to build a full self sufficient OCS Unix Agent for AIX
I already manager to make the agent work but now I need to make it work with Expat without( the need to have it installed on my local machine

@ArnaudDubois The following works for me: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-docker-xml-parser. Let me know if this is of any help

I finally managed to make my agent work using Alien::Expat and by appending the LIBPATH variable with the path where the libexpat.h has been built
So, I keep XML::SImple and  XML::SAX::Expat as parser and I use Alien::Expat to provide the necessary libraries
